# How do I find out if I've installed Ruby via RVM, chruby, rbenv or other?

Tags: ruby, macos

I have Ruby installed on my Mac, probably by me about a year ago.

How do I find out how the currently used Ruby version on my computer was installed?

Comment: Try this `whereis ruby` command.. And `which ruby` will tell you about the currently used Ruby

Comment: Thanks. `which ruby` returned `/Users/MyUserName/.rbenv/shims/ruby`, so it was rbenv.

Comment: In some cases you might want to use `which -a`, if the ruby command is wrapped by something else e.g. `bundled_ruby`